# Windows Phone 8.1 WinJS Keyboard Page Resize

Tags: winjs, windows-phone-8.1

I am currently writing an app using WinJS with Windows Phone 8.1. The issue I am encountering now, is that whenever a user taps on a login input box the keyboard appears and displaces the page. This makes the page longer and scrollable; how do I prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to prevent this with the [EnsuredFocusedElementInView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.inputpanevisibilityeventargs.ensuredfocusedelementinview.aspx) property.

You can register an event listener to fire when virtual keyboard starts showing, and set `event.ensuredFocusedElementInView = true` to prevent the app from resizing the visual viewport, which is what causes the longer, scrollable, page.

```
// React to Soft Keyboard events
var virtualKeyboard = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.InputPane.getForCurrentView();
virtualKeyboard.addEventListener("showing", function (event) {
  event.ensuredFocusedElementInView = true; // Prevent visual viewport resize.
  }, false);
```